# In Elasticsearch Nest mapping one type to another

Tags: elasticsearch, uuid, nest

I am using the elasticsearch nest C# library to map documents. Everything goes smooth except a custom type, TypeX, I have which is treated as an object and stored as { }.

This custom type is a [v1 uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) and is essentially treated as Guid. I would honestly like to cast it as a Guid for storage purposes since it implicitly casts back and forth. Thus elastic would see it as a Guid and not TypeX.

According to the [attribute mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/attribute-mapping.html) section it seems I can change the type that way however I don't really want to expose Nest as a dependency for my type since it is used in numerous places.

Is it possible to setup this mapping from the connection or the Index to map TypeX to Guid and Guid to TypeX?

Nest: 6.0.1

ES: 6.2.2

Comment: What version of NEST are you using, and what version of Elasticsearch are you targeting?

Comment: I just installed both new so that would be and added versions to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`System.Guid` is mapped as a `keyword` data type with automapping with NEST. Given the following document

```
public class MyDocument
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

and the following mapping

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("foo", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
        )
    )
);
```

will produce

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "mydocument": {
      "properties": {
        "userId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, for your own type to be mapped as a `keyword` type, you can use fluent mapping if you don't want to attribute the POCO. Given the following POCO and custom `Uuid` type

```
public class Uuid
{
    private string _value;

    public Uuid(string value) => _value = value;

    public override string ToString() => _value;
}

public class MyDocument
{
    public Uuid UserId { get; set; }
}
```

these can be mapped with

```
var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("foo", c => c
    .Mappings(m => m
        .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm
            .AutoMap()
            .Properties(p => p
                .Keyword(k => k
                    .Name(n => n.UserId)
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which produces the same mapping as before. However, *this is only half of the story*, because we also need to control how `Uuid` is serialized and deserialized such that it is serialized as a JSON `string` and an instance can be constructed from a `string`. In NEST 6.x, we would need to [use our own serializer for this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/custom-serialization.html), since the serializer used by NEST is internal.

The [`NEST.JsonSerializer` nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST.JsonNetSerializer/) contains a custom serializer that uses Json.NET, so you can write a `JsonConverter` to take care of serialization of the `Uuid` type

```
public class UuidConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
        typeof(Uuid).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) =>
        reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String
            ? new Uuid((string)reader.Value)
            : null;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (value != null)
            writer.WriteValue(value.ToString());
        else
            writer.WriteNull();       
    }
}

private static void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

    // configure NEST to use Json.NET for serialization of your documents
    // and register a custom converter to handle Uuid type
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool, (builtin, s) => 
        new JsonNetSerializer(builtin, s, contractJsonConverters:
            new [] { new UuidConverter() }
        ))
        .DefaultIndex("foo");

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    var createIndexResponse = client.CreateIndex("foo", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<MyDocument>(mm => mm
                .AutoMap()
                .Properties(p => p
                    .Keyword(k => k
                        .Name(n => n.UserId)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    );

    var document = new MyDocument
    {
        UserId = new Uuid("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000")  
    };

    var indexResponse = client.IndexDocument(document);
}
```

The document indexing request then serializes `Uuid` as a string

```
POST http://localhost:9200/foo/mydocument
{
  "userId": "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluent mapping instead of attribute mapping (next page in your attribute mapping link)

Comment: I did read that however it is not clear how to go from object to object. On the documentation it states "each property of the POCO".

Comment: If TypeX is an object and not a property then you use the Nested mapping, if it is just a property of type Guid then using AutoMap() function will map it as a keyword.

Comment: I was trying to avoid having to do this for every usage however it seems that is how it needs to be.